# How to make fast resize of images to gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

i have a gridview and a list of all images on device
i am trying to display them on gridview with resizing them to fixed size 250x250px in gridview adapter with

```
Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, width, true);
```

but it is too slow
is there a way to display them faster?

i also try to get MINI_KIND with

```
  Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    activity.getContentResolver(), Long.parseLong(thumb),
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, bmOptions);
```

but this way takes a lot of memory (80mb for 90 pics) as i keep all bitmaps in arraylist

Comment: dont do them all at once you are not showing all 90 images on the screen  so there is no need, lazy load them in

Answer (score 0):

you should cache bitmaps. Details: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

Bitmaps eat memory. I would not keep the actual bitmaps in an array, but rather the URI for the image resource.

I would also think about using a Surface view for the images and drawing them in a grid. You could then draw the bitmaps into the view and recycle them after drawing them to the canvas. If they are relatively static you can draw them once and then save a single bitmap of all the scaled images.

Also maybe try loading with RGB_565 to reduce the memory usage.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html